# Durable messaging

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, messaging

Does GCP have a service to provide durable messaging where messages don't expire after a short period? I've looked into PubSub, which has a maximum retention of 31 days on the topic level. While it's better than 7 days, it's still hardly could be considered durable messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, GCP does not have a service to provide durable messaging, with a maximum retention policy of > 31 days.

Although GCP allows third-party integrations like Apache Kafka.
[Apache Kafka - Integration guide GCP](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/connectors/apachekafka/configure)

Apache Kafka allows you to configure the retention period based on your needs.

Comment: It's mind boggling that there's no native service to provide even a basic queuing service with a decent retention time. Kafka would be an overkill in this scenario, but I guess running [RabbitMQ](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/connectors/rabbitmq) would be an option. Wouldn't want to use a non PaaS option though.

Comment: Yaa, it is surprising.